# Kibana does not pick timestamp format epoch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-6

I am sending logs from the fluent-amqp plugin that adds a field `timestamp` with the format epoch such as:

```
{
  "key": "somekey",
  "timestamp": 1547769614,
  "payload": {
    "log": "some logs",
    "stream": "stdout"
  }
}
```

However, I am not able to pick timestamp field in the time picker in Kibana to set it as `_time`.
I have tried to add a *metaField* from the Settings called *timestamp* and *_timestamp* without success as, even if I can pick that as a time picker, it is not being interpreted in the search page, resulting in empty logs.

Is there a template to add? A settings to tick? Or should I update the upstream plugin directly?
I am using version 6.5.4.

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your index?

Comment: Sure. Sorry for the invalid JSON. It looks like that for the 3 main fields (`key`, `timestamp`, `payload`): {
  "myindex": {
    "mappings": {
      "-": {
        "properties": {
          "key": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "payload": {
            "properties": {
                          },
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: Yeah, well, `timestamp` is of type `long` while it should be `date`. You need to change your mapping and reindex your data. You also probably need to either pre-configure your index before sending data to it.

Comment: Should I do that from fluentd when sending logs or is there a way to automatically convert that field on any new index from Elasticserach?

Comment: You're using the fluentd elasticsearch plugin?

Comment: fluentd to rabbitmq to a worker that populate indices based on some fluentd fields

Comment: What's the index name you're using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have decided to fork the ruby plugin and to convert the epoch time to an Elasticsearch readable time format like: `"2019-01-21T01:18:39+00:00"`.
It is working well and I can pick that field up in Kibana.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) that will be used for all future indexes created by your worker.

```
PUT _template/my-index-template
{
  "index-patterns": ["myindex*"],          <--- replace your real index name/pattern here
  "mappings": {
    "-": {
      "properties": {
        "key": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "payload": {
          "properties": {}
        },
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "date"                   <-- this is what changed
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My indices are like `*-*-*`, which is also the case for `.monitoring-es-*` and other system indices. I can't really specify them all like that. Also the mapping is quite complex if I need to define it entirely and I guess that I will be stucked to that specific schema, which I don't want. Is there any other solution?